# Store/Load a modified HTML5 Page from localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to store a (with JS) modified HTML5 Page to localStorage and load it at the next visit of this Page?

I try to set somewhere on the Page a Tag by my Chrome Extension and load it again.

Comment: Is it a browser cache for this purpose?

Comment: This seems like a bad idea... Why not just store the data you need to set the tag, rather than the whole page?

Comment: localStorage object provides a Storage object for an `origin`, look for it while using `content scripts`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup.

You can even run this on this very page.

1) Modify the page.

```
document.querySelector('#hlogo').innerHTML = '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a7/Siamese_Cat_Cross-Eyed.jpg/1280px-Siamese_Cat_Cross-Eyed.jpg">';
```

2) Save the page.

```
localStorage['thispage'] = document.querySelector('html').innerHTML;
```

3) Refresh the page.

4) Restore it from localStorage

```
document.querySelector('html').innerHTML = localStorage['thispage'];
```